# Connect failed to mongodb shell

Tags: mongodb

I have installed mongo, run the shell success in couple of time, then I try to add:

`security:
    authorization: disabled`

because I want to add user Admin to admin db. After that, I can not access the mongo shell, this error show up when run command `mongo`

`MongoDB shell version v3.6.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-02-09T09:34:48.769+0700 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, in(checking socket for error after poll), reason: Connection refused
2018-02-09T09:34:48.769+0700 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed`

And here is few last lines of the log file after disable authorization, even when enable it again, thing doesn't work `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

`2018-02-09T09:33:00.843+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: Access control is not enabled for the database.
2018-02-09T09:33:00.843+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **          Read and write access to data and configuration is unrestricted.
2018-02-09T09:33:00.843+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2018-02-09T09:33:00.847+0700 F CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** IMPORTANT: UPGRADE PROBLEM: The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6; see http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/3.6-upgrade-fcv for more details.
2018-02-09T09:33:00.847+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.847+0700 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2018-02-09T09:33:00.847+0700 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing all drop-pending collections...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.847+0700 I REPL     [initandlisten] shutdown: removing checkpointTimestamp collection...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.848+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: waiting for fs preallocator...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.848+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: final commit...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.849+0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journalCleanup...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.849+0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] removeJournalFiles
2018-02-09T09:33:00.876+0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] old journal file /var/lib/mongodb/journal/j._0 will be reused as /var/lib/mongodb/journal/prealloc.0
2018-02-09T09:33:00.899+0700 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] Terminating durability thread ...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.950+0700 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread stopped
2018-02-09T09:33:00.950+0700 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread stopped
2018-02-09T09:33:00.950+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: closing all files...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.953+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] closeAllFiles() finished
2018-02-09T09:33:00.953+0700 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] shutdown: removing fs lock...
2018-02-09T09:33:00.953+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2018-02-09T09:33:00.953+0700 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:62`

I tried to run `sudo service mongod restart` but doesn't work.
So can you give me some advices for this problem, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is seems that mongod can't start because your system has updated mongodb from version < 3.4 to 3.6 as it stated in the log: `The data files need to be fully upgraded to version 3.4 before attempting an upgrade to 3.6`

You need to downgrade mongodb to 3.4, then `sudo service mongod start` to trigger the db migration to 3.4.

Comment: Mongo update automatically right? should I pin the version to 3.4?

Comment: After downgrading to 3.4 and complete the data migration, you can upgrade again to 3.6. The point is you cannot skip version because it's part of db migration.

Answer (score 1):

I just try to run this command and it works for me `brew services start mongodb`

Cheers.

Comment: that's true, my problem is about version conflict between my pymongo, mongoengine and mongodb. So when I installed the correct version for each of those, it worked. Reload, restart or repair mongodb will help sometimes as well.